# Unable to generate signed APK with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, proguard, android-proguard

So, I was able to generate signed APK before I added these two Firebase libraries to my project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'


compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:10.2.6'
```

This is the error I'm getting when I tried to generate signed APK:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:com.google.firebase.appindexing.internal.zzd$zzb: can't find referenced method 'android.os.IInterface zzwW()' in program class com.google.firebase.appindexing.internal.zzc
Warning:com.google.firebase.appindexing.internal.zzf: can't find referenced method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task doWrite(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabn)' in program class com.google.firebase.appindexing.internal.zzf$zza
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
Error:java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 2m 50s
Information:2 errors
Information:4 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you also using Firebase App Indexing in your app?  The error message makes it sound like it's there.

Comment: @DougStevenson Actually I'm unable to generate signed apk whenever I use version 10.2.6 or higher

Comment: Are all the versions of all the Firebase and Play Services dependencies exactly the same?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines into your proguard file.

```
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.appindexing.internal.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.appindexing.internal.** { *; }
```